# guarded_thread class: move assignment operator error

Tags: c++, multithreading

Stroustrup has illustrated a guarded_thread class that inherits from thread and uses RAII on it ("The C++ Programming Language", 4th Ed, pg1215):

```
struct guarded_thread : std::thread
{
   /// inherit the thread class' constructor
   /// [CPL], $20.3.5.1
   using std::thread::thread;

   ~guarded_thread()
   {
      if (joinable())
         join();
   }
};
```

I have tested this using code (also provided by Stroustrup): http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/da67ae51157bcbe4

```
/// simple use of a guard
void run(int i, int n)
{
   guarded_thread t1 {f};
   guarded_thread t2;

   vector<T> v;

   /// ...

   if (i < n)
   {
      thread t3 {g};

      /// ...

      /// move t3 to outer scope
      t2 = move(t3);
   }

   /// might throw
   v[i] = T {};

   /// ...

   cout << "i="  << i
        << " n=" << n
        << "  OK" << endl;
}
```

However, the following compilation error occurs for the tester:

```
main.cpp:51:10: error: no viable overloaded '='

      t2 = move(t3);
      ~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~

./guarded_thread.h:12:8: note: candidate function (the implicit copy assignment operator) not viable: no known conversion from 'typename remove_reference<thread &>::type' (aka 'std::__1::thread') to 'const guarded_thread' for 1st argument

struct guarded_thread : std::thread
       ^
1 error generated.
```

The guarded_thread class also can't inherit the assignment operator of the thread class, since the latter is private.

How do I fix this error?

Comment: "The guarded_thread class also can't inherit the assignment operator of the thread class, since the latter is private." Which one? The move-assignment one is public.

Comment: [No it's not private](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/operator%3D)

Comment: Well, I get the following error when I try to inherit it:     ./guarded_thread.h:17:23: error: 'operator=' is a private member of 'std::__1::thread'. See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b7f87113576e983).

Comment: That is just a quirk of `libc++`, that you seem to use for some unclear reason. [It builds and works when we remove `-stdlib=libc++` from the command line](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c5d00d0039b5e45).

Comment: @StoryTeller, you are absolutely right.